# 2 $\times$ 2 Symmetry matrices of a square

Tags: matrices, group-theory, symmetry

I have a square with vertices at the points (2,2), (-2,2),(-2,-2) and (2,-2). I am looking to find the 8 2 $\times$ 2 matrices corresponding to the square symmetries. I have used this resource http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-group-of-symmetries-of-the-square to calculate the rotational symmetries, however, I can not figure out how to express the flip (reflection) symmetries in matrix form. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

look at the matrices:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\
-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and the way these matrices transform the vectors of the basis $[1,0]^T$ and $[0,1]^T$.

Comment: Ah Ok. I see now! Thanks!